# Is it possible to use backreferrences in notepad++?

Tags: notepad++, regex

In my specific example, for a selection of lines I want to duplicate them inline, separated by an arbitrary marker

Ie,

```
stringA
stringB
```

becomes

```
stringA_something_stringA
stringB_something_stringB
```

Altough I'm mediocre with regex, I believe this should be accomplished by searching for something like:

```
(string.)_something_(string.)
```

and replacing with

```
\1_something_\1
```

However I'm unable to get even simple \1 replacements working. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your replacement regex is correct, however your match will not work as there is only 1 world per line. You are trying to match the replacement text which is not yet there :)

try this:

```
(string.)
```

replace with `\1_something_\1`.

Make sure you are using regex mode as well.

Comment: Ty JohnT (and Sonny) for the answer. JohnT. I still don't follow why the search string doesn't work though. Even consdiering just one line (one world) I would have thought that "(string.)_something_(string.)" matches "stringA_something_stringA".

Comment: @RJF I thought you were replacing StringA and StringB with `stringA_something_stringA` and `stringB_something_stringB` ? In that case you cannot search for text that is not already there.

Comment: Oh, yeah. Confusing myself there. Tyvm.

Answer (score 1):

Find what: `(string.)`
Replace with: `\1_something_\1`